# What does "ACFT MAX 65/7 " means on lido charts?

Tags: commercial-aviation, general-aviation, airbus-a320, aeronautical-charts

What does "**ACFT MAX 65/7**" on the minima box means? I found out that its related to wingspan and some vertical distance, but I still didn't get the vertical distance thing !!

Comment: https://www.pprune.org/questions/554129-lido-65-7-minima.html states that the 7 relates to less than 7m vertical distance required between the paths that wheels and glide slope antenna follow on the approach. It also offers the notion that these minima can only ever be used by A380 at the moment.

Comment: so the 7 m vertical distance is when the a/c on the ground or during landing ?! , i still can't imagine he picture in my head .

Comment: It’s during approach. The aircraft will travel on a slope pointing 3° downwards, so all its parts will do, too. The aircraft will travel on that path with a certain, in the context of this exercise predefined, body angle (often with the nose pointing slightly upwards). This will lead to the GS antenna (probably in the nose) following a different path than the main gear (but obviously parallel and pointing downward at 3°). Trace these paths, draw a vertical line intersecting both, measure the distance between the paths on this line. Still posting as comment due unconfirmed reference.